# Playing an mp3 using a variable from a text file in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
myfile = open('kill.txt', encoding='utf-8').readlines()
NoiseMP3 = myfile[3]

bop = pygame.mixer.music.load(NoiseMP3)
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

Simply, the name of the file is on line 3. The file is there and works if i change NoiseMP3 to the file name.

i get back

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\いち suffering\Words\Words.py", line 66, in <module>
    bop = pygame.mixer.music.load(NoiseMP3)
pygame.error: Couldn't open 'wear.mp3'
```

Comment: You did not really ask a question. What do you mean by "i get back"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not dealing with the line return at the end of the line.
Try:

`NoiseMP3 = myfile[3].strip()`